# Скопировать svg с анимацией с сайта

Tags: javascript, svg, jsx

Пытаюсь скопировать svg с анимацией с сайта nextjs.org:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

но ничего не выходит:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал стырить целиком сайт, но там jsx сбилженный и тоже не могу разобраться как это в нормальный jsx законвертить, помогите пожалуйста :)

```js
function eH(e) {
        let t = L.useRef(null),
          s = (0, E.Y)(t, { once: !0, margin: "-35%" }),
          i = {
            animate: { pathLength: s ? 1 : 0, transition: { duration: 1.2 } },
          },
          a = {
            animate: {
              opacity: s ? 1 : 0,
              transition: { delay: 1, duration: 0.5 },
            },
          };
        return (0, r.jsx)(ek.Provider, {
          value: { isInView: s },
          children: (0, r.jsxs)("svg", {
            fill: "none",
            height: "264",
            ref: t,
            role: "img",
            viewBox: "0 0 891 264",
            width: "891",
            ...e,
            "aria-label":
              "A bunch of connecting lines that form into the CPU, with the text Powered By on top of the the CPU. Gradient lines are animating along the drawn lines, dissolving into the CPU in the center.",
            children: [
              (0, r.jsx)(W.E.path, {
                d: "M388 96L388 68C388 65.7909 386.209 64 384 64L310 64",
                stroke: "var(--geist-foreground)",
                strokeOpacity: "0.1",
                ...i,
                transition: { delay: 1 - 0.9 },
              }),
              (0, r.jsx)(W.E.path, {
                d: "M349 150L73 150C70.7909 150 69 151.791 69 154L69 174",
                stroke: "var(--geist-foreground)",
                strokeOpacity: "0.1",
                ...i,
                transition: { delay: 1 - 0.8 },
              }),
              (0, r.jsxs)("g", {
                children: [
                  (0, r.jsx)(W.E.path, {
                    d: "M547 130L822 130C824.209 130 826 131.791 826 134L826 264",
                    stroke: "var(--geist-foreground)",
                    strokeOpacity: "0.1",
                    ...i,
                    transition: { delay: 1 - 0.7 },
                  }),
                  (0, r.jsx)("path", {
                    d: "M547 130L822 130C824.209 130 826 131.791 826 134L826 264",
                    stroke: "url(#orange-pulse-1)",
                    strokeWidth: "2",
                  }),
                ],
              }),
              (0, r.jsxs)("g", {
                children: [
                  (0, r.jsx)(W.E.path, {
                    d: "M349 130L5.00002 130C2.79088 130 1.00001 131.791 1.00001 134L1.00001 264",
                    stroke: "var(--geist-foreground)",
                    strokeOpacity: "0.1",
                    ...i,
                    transition: { delay: 0.4 },
                  }),
                  (0, r.jsx)("path", {
                    d: "M349 130L5.00002 130C2.79088 130 1.00001 131.791 1.00001 134L1.00001 264",
                    stroke: "url(#blue-pulse-1)",
                    strokeLinecap: "round",
                    strokeWidth: "2",
                  }),
                ],
              }),
              (0, r.jsxs)("g", {
                children: [
                  (0, r.jsx)(W.E.path, {
                    d: "M547 150L633 150C635.209 150 637 151.791 637 154L637 236C637 238.209 635.209 240 633 240L488 240C485.791 240 484 241.791 484 244L484 264",
                    stroke: "var(--geist-foreground)",
                    strokeOpacity: "0.1",
                    ...i,
                    transition: { delay: 0.5 },
                  }),
                  (0, r.jsx)("path", {
                    d: "M547 150L633 150C635.209 150 637 151.791 637 154L637 236C637 238.209 635.209 240 633 240L488 240C485.791 240 484 241.791 484 244L484 264",
                    stroke: "url(#pink-pulse-2)",
                    strokeLinecap: "round",
                    strokeWidth: "2",
                  }),
                ],
              }),
              (0, r.jsxs)("g", {
                children: [
                  (0, r.jsx)(W.E.path, {
                    d: "M388 184L388 194C388 196.209 386.209 198 384 198L77 198C74.7909 198 73 199.791 73 202L73 264",
                    stroke: "var(--geist-foreground)",
                    strokeOpacity: "0.1",
                    ...i,
                    transition: { delay: 0.6 },
                  }),
                  (0, r.jsx)("path", {
                    d: "M388 184L388 194C388 196.209 386.209 198 384 198L77 198C74.7909 198 73 199.791 73 202L73 264",
                    stroke: "url(#blue-pulse-2)",
                    strokeLinecap: "round",
                    strokeWidth: "2",
                  }),
                ],
              }),
              (0, r.jsx)(W.E.path, {
                d: "M412 96L412 0",
                stroke: "url(#paint0_linear_341_27683)",
                strokeOpacity: "0.1",
                ...i,
                transition: { delay: 0.7 },
              }),
              (0, r.jsxs)("g", {
                children: [
                  (0, r.jsx)(W.E.path, {
                    d: "M412 263.5L412 184",
                    stroke: "var(--geist-foreground)",
                    strokeOpacity: "0.1",
                    ...i,
                    animate: { ...i.animate, scale: "-1" },
                    transition: { delay: 0.8 },
                  }),
                  (0, r.jsx)("path", {
                    d: "M412 263.5L412 184",
                    stroke: "url(#pink-pulse-1)",
                    strokeLinecap: "round",
                    strokeWidth: "2",
                  }),
                ],
              }),
              (0, r.jsxs)("g", {
                children: [
                  (0, r.jsx)(W.E.path, {
                    d: "M508 96L508 88C508 85.7909 509.791 84 512 84L886 84C888.209 84 890 85.7909 890 88L890 264",
                    stroke: "var(--geist-foreground)",
                    strokeOpacity: "0.1",
                    ...i,
                    transition: { delay: 0.9 },
                  }),
                  (0, r.jsx)("path", {
                    d: "M508 96L508 88C508 85.7909 509.791 84 512 84L886 84C888.209 84 890 85.7909 890 88L890 264",
                    stroke: "url(#orange-pulse-2)",
                    strokeWidth: "2",
                  }),
                ],
              }),
              (0, r.jsx)(W.E.path, {
                d: "M436 96L436 0",
                stroke: "url(#paint1_linear_341_27683)",
                strokeOpacity: "0.1",
                ...i,
                transition: { delay: 1 },
              }),
              (0, r.jsx)(W.E.path, {
                d: "M436 214L436 184",
                stroke: "var(--geist-foreground)",
                strokeOpacity: "0.1",
                ...i,
                animate: { ...i.animate, scale: "-1" },
                transition: { delay: 1 },
              }),
              (0, r.jsx)(W.E.path, {
                d: "M460 96L460 64",
                stroke: "var(--geist-foreground)",
                strokeOpacity: "0.1",
                ...i,
                transition: { delay: 1 },
              }),
              (0, r.jsx)(W.E.path, {
                d: "M460 239L460 184",
                stroke: "var(--geist-foreground)",
                strokeOpacity: "0.1",
                ...i,
                animate: { ...i.animate, scale: "-1" },
                transition: { delay: 1 },
              }),
              (0, r.jsx)(W.E.path, {
                d: "M484 96L484 24C484 21.7909 485.791 20 488 20L554 20",
                stroke: "url(#paint2_linear_341_27683)",
                strokeOpacity: "0.1",
                ...i,
                transition: { delay: 1 },
              }),
              (0, r.jsx)(W.E.path, {
                d: "M484 184L484 210C484 212.209 485.791 214 488 214L560 214",
                stroke: "var(--geist-foreground)",
                strokeOpacity: "0.1",
                ...i,
                transition: { delay: 1 },
              }),
              (0, r.jsx)(W.E.path, {
                d: "M508 184L508 193C508 195.209 509.791 197 512 197L560 197",
                stroke: "var(--geist-foreground)",
                strokeOpacity: "0.1",
                ...i,
                transition: { delay: 1 },
              }),
              (0, r.jsx)(W.E.circle, {
                ...a,
                cx: "460",
                cy: "64",
                fill: "var(--geist-background)",
                r: "4",
              }),
              (0, r.jsx)(W.E.circle, {
                ...a,
                cx: "460",
                cy: "64",
                r: "3.5",
                stroke: "var(--geist-foreground)",
                strokeOpacity: "0.1",
              }),
              (0, r.jsx)(W.E.circle, {
                ...a,
                cx: "308",
                cy: "64",
                fill: "var(--geist-background)",
                r: "4",
              }),
              (0, r.jsx)(W.E.circle, {
                ...a,
                cx: "308",
                cy: "64",
                r: "3.5",
                stroke: "var(--geist-foreground)",
                strokeOpacity: "0.1",
              }),
              (0, r.jsx)(W.E.circle, {
                ...a,
                cx: "69",
                cy: "173",
                fill: "var(--geist-background)",
                r: "4",
              }),
              (0, r.jsx)(W.E.circle, {
                ...a,
                cx: "69",
                cy: "173",
                r: "3.5",
                stroke: "var(--geist-foreground)",
                strokeOpacity: "0.1",
              }),
              (0, r.jsx)(W.E.circle, {
                ...a,
                cx: "436",
                cy: "214",
                fill: "var(--geist-background)",
                r: "4",
              }),
              (0, r.jsx)(W.E.circle, {
                ...a,
                cx: "436",
                cy: "214",
                r: "3.5",
                stroke: "var(--geist-foreground)",
                strokeOpacity: "0.1",
              }),
              (0, r.jsx)(W.E.circle, {
                ...a,
                cx: "460",
                cy: "240",
                fill: "var(--geist-background)",
                r: "4",
              }),
              (0, r.jsx)(W.E.circle, {
                ...a,
                cx: "460",
                cy: "240",
                r: "3.5",
                stroke: "var(--geist-foreground)",
                strokeOpacity: "0.1",
              }),
              (0, r.jsx)(W.E.circle, {
                ...a,
                cx: "560",
                cy: "214",
                fill: "var(--geist-background)",
                r: "4",
              }),
              (0, r.jsx)(W.E.circle, {
                ...a,
                cx: "560",
                cy: "214",
                r: "3.5",
                stroke: "var(--geist-foreground)",
                strokeOpacity: "0.1",
              }),
              (0, r.jsx)(W.E.circle, {
                ...a,
                cx: "560",
                cy: "197",
                fill: "var(--geist-background)",
                r: "4",
              }),
              (0, r.jsx)(W.E.circle, {
                ...a,
                cx: "560",
                cy: "197",
                r: "3.5",
                stroke: "var(--geist-foreground)",
                strokeOpacity: "0.1",
              }),
              (0, r.jsxs)("defs", {
                children: [
                  (0, r.jsxs)("linearGradient", {
                    gradientUnits: "userSpaceOnUse",
                    id: "paint0_linear_341_27683",
                    x1: "412.5",
                    x2: "412.5",
                    y1: "-3.27835e-08",
                    y2: "96",
                    children: [
                      (0, r.jsx)("stop", { stopOpacity: "0" }),
                      (0, r.jsx)("stop", { offset: "1" }),
                    ],
                  }),
                  (0, r.jsxs)("linearGradient", {
                    gradientUnits: "userSpaceOnUse",
                    id: "paint1_linear_341_27683",
                    x1: "436.5",
                    x2: "436.5",
                    y1: "-3.27835e-08",
                    y2: "96",
                    children: [
                      (0, r.jsx)("stop", { stopOpacity: "0" }),
                      (0, r.jsx)("stop", { offset: "1" }),
                    ],
                  }),
                  (0, r.jsxs)("linearGradient", {
                    gradientUnits: "userSpaceOnUse",
                    id: "paint2_linear_341_27683",
                    x1: "554",
                    x2: "484",
                    y1: "20",
                    y2: "96",
                    children: [
                      (0, r.jsx)("stop", { stopOpacity: "0" }),
                      (0, r.jsx)("stop", { offset: "1" }),
                    ],
                  }),
                  (0, r.jsxs)(eV, {
                    animate: {
                      x1: [83, 400],
                      x2: [83, 350],
                      y1: [320, 83],
                      y2: [415, 133.75],
                    },
                    id: "blue-pulse-1",
                    transition: {
                      duration: 2.2,
                      repeat: 1 / 0,
                      repeatDelay: 1.4,
                      delay: 0.5,
                    },
                    children: [
                      (0, r.jsx)("stop", {
                        stopColor: "#2EB9DF",
                        stopOpacity: "0",
                      }),
                      (0, r.jsx)("stop", {
                        offset: "0.05",
                        stopColor: "#2EB9DF",
                      }),
                      (0, r.jsx)("stop", {
                        offset: "1",
                        stopColor: "#2EB9DF",
                        stopOpacity: "0",
                      }),
                    ],
                  }),
                  (0, r.jsxs)(eV, {
                    animate: {
                      x1: [83, 400],
                      x2: [83, 350],
                      y1: [267.5, 83],
                      y2: [300, 133.75],
                    },
                    id: "blue-pulse-2",
                    transition: {
                      duration: 2,
                      repeat: 1 / 0,
                      repeatDelay: 1.2,
                    },
                    children: [
                      (0, r.jsx)("stop", {
                        stopColor: "#2EB9DF",
                        stopOpacity: "0",
                      }),
                      (0, r.jsx)("stop", {
                        offset: "0.05",
                        stopColor: "#2EB9DF",
                      }),
                      (0, r.jsx)("stop", {
                        offset: "1",
                        stopColor: "#2EB9DF",
                        stopOpacity: "0",
                      }),
                    ],
                  }),
                  (0, r.jsxs)(eV, {
                    animate: {
                      x1: [412, 400],
                      y1: [264, 83],
                      x2: [412, 350],
                      y2: [304, 133.75],
                    },
                    id: "pink-pulse-1",
                    transition: {
                      duration: 0.9,
                      repeat: 1 / 0,
                      repeatDelay: 1.9,
                      delay: 0.3,
                    },
                    children: [
                      (0, r.jsx)("stop", {
                        stopColor: "#FF4A81",
                        stopOpacity: "0",
                      }),
                      (0, r.jsx)("stop", {
                        offset: "0.030",
                        stopColor: "#FF4A81",
                      }),
                      (0, r.jsx)("stop", {
                        offset: "0.27",
                        stopColor: "#DF6CF6",
                      }),
                      (0, r.jsx)("stop", {
                        offset: "1",
                        stopColor: "#0196FF",
                        stopOpacity: "0",
                      }),
                    ],
                  }),
                  (0, r.jsxs)(eV, {
                    animate: {
                      x1: [490, 490, 480, 478, 475],
                      x2: [490, 479, 488],
                      y1: [266, 120],
                      y2: [284, 150],
                    },
                    id: "pink-pulse-2",
                    transition: {
                      duration: 2.2,
                      repeat: 1 / 0,
                      repeatDelay: 1.8,
                      delay: 0.5,
                    },
                    children: [
                      (0, r.jsx)("stop", {
                        stopColor: "#FF4A81",
                        stopOpacity: "0",
                      }),
                      (0, r.jsx)("stop", {
                        offset: "0.0564843",
                        stopColor: "#FF4A81",
                      }),
                      (0, r.jsx)("stop", {
                        offset: "0.4616",
                        stopColor: "#DF6CF6",
                      }),
                      (0, r.jsx)("stop", {
                        offset: "1",
                        stopColor: "#0196FF",
                        stopOpacity: "0",
                      }),
                    ],
                  }),
                  (0, r.jsxs)(eV, {
                    animate: {
                      x1: [826, 360],
                      x2: [826, 400],
                      y1: [270, 130],
                      y2: [340, 170],
                    },
                    id: "orange-pulse-1",
                    transition: {
                      duration: 2,
                      repeat: 1 / 0,
                      repeatDelay: 1.8,
                      delay: 0.6,
                    },
                    children: [
                      (0, r.jsx)("stop", {
                        stopColor: "#FF7432",
                        stopOpacity: "0",
                      }),
                      (0, r.jsx)("stop", {
                        offset: "0.0550784",
                        stopColor: "#FF7432",
                      }),
                      (0, r.jsx)("stop", {
                        offset: "0.373284",
                        stopColor: "#F7CC4B",
                      }),
                      (0, r.jsx)("stop", {
                        offset: "1",
                        stopColor: "#F7CC4B",
                        stopOpacity: "0",
                      }),
                    ],
                  }),
                  (0, r.jsxs)(eV, {
                    animate: {
                      x1: [868, 300],
                      x2: [868, 400],
                      y1: [280, 140],
                      y2: [440, 180],
                    },
                    id: "orange-pulse-2",
                    transition: {
                      duration: 2.5,
                      repeat: 1 / 0,
                      repeatDelay: 2,
                      delay: 0.9,
                    },
                    children: [
                      (0, r.jsx)("stop", {
                        stopColor: "#FF7432",
                        stopOpacity: "0",
                      }),
                      (0, r.jsx)("stop", {
                        offset: "0.0531089",
                        stopColor: "#FF7432",
                      }),
                      (0, r.jsx)("stop", {
                        offset: "0.415114",
                        stopColor: "#F7CC4B",
                      }),
                      (0, r.jsx)("stop", {
                        offset: "1",
                        stopColor: "#F7CC4B",
                        stopOpacity: "0",
                      }),
                    ],
                  }),
                ],
              }),
            ],
          }),
        });
      }
```

Comment: Зачем что то тырить?Можно же самому сделать, может быть не совсем так но всё равно получится

Comment: Действительно не самая сложная анимация, чтобы её тырить. По анимации path есть куча статей, [например](https://habr.com/ru/articles/207908/), отблеск можно анимировать [как-то так](https://codepen.io/shahbokhari/pen/oBbmXG) и кучей других способов.